# Make/make install to custom directory

Tags: c, shell, gcc, makefile

I am trying to install [this](http://www.surdeanu.name/mihai/swirl/index.php) to my webserver, which I have through a shared hosting company. In the installation instructions, it tells me to navigate to the program's directory, then use the shell commands ./configure, make, and make install to install the program. When I enter ./configure, everything executes fine. But when I enter make, it says

```
cd . && /bin/sh /home/blahblahname/swirl-1.1.0/config/missing --run aclocal-1.10
/home/blahblahname/swirl-1.1.0/config/missing: line 54:
aclocal-1.10: command not found WARNING: `aclocal-1.10' is missing on
your system.  You should only need it if
         you modified `acinclude.m4' or `configure.ac'.  You might want
         to install the `Automake' and `Perl' packages.  Grab them from
         any GNU archive site.
cd . && /bin/sh /home/blahblahname/swirl-1.1.0/config/missing --run automake-1.10 --gnu
/home/blahblahname/swirl-1.1.0/config/missing: line 54: automake-1.10: command not found
WARNING: `automake-1.10' is missing on your system.  You should only need it if
         you modified `Makefile.am', `acinclude.m4' or `configure.ac'.
         You might want to install the `Automake' and `Perl' packages.
         Grab them from any GNU archive site.
/home/blahblahname/swirl-1.1.0/config/missing: line 185:
/usr/bin/find: Permission denied
cd . && /bin/sh /home/blahblahname/swirl-1.1.0/config/missing --run autoconf autoconf:
configure.in: No such file or directory make: *** [configure] Error 1
```

Same thing with make install. It looks like I don't have access to the directory it's trying to install to. Is there a way I can get this to work without access to that directory? Maybe I can set a custom make/make install location somehow?

Comment: It seems like your shared host doesn't include the necessary tools to build applications. Also, you can't do `make install` if it's a shared host, not unless you have root privileges (which I doubt) or can write to the `/usr/local` folder. When you do `configure` add the argument `--prefix=$HOME` (you may replace `$HOME` with some other place you have the right to write files).

Comment: Upon further inspection, it seems nothing changes when I do ./configure, or ./configure --prefix=$HOME. No news files or folders in my home directory, as far as I can see. When I do make with that argument, I get the same error as before. Is there anything else I can try, or should I contact my hosting provider to see if they can install it for me?

Comment: The thing about changing prefix is for installation, later. The problem you have now is that your host doesn't have the tools needed to build applications from scratch.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So could I compile it on my computer, transfer it to the webserver, then run it from the shell on there?

Comment: The problem is not that your host is missing the tools, but simply that the timestamps are off in the tarball.  Perhaps you've unpacked it on an NFS drive with incorrect time stamps.  aclocal is *not* required to build the package unless either you have modified the meta-files configure.in/ac, Makefile.am, etc, their timestamps are wrong, or the original tarball is hosed.  Try updating the timestamps on every other file in the unpacked directory so that everything else is newer than all of the Makefile.am, configure.ac, and acinclude.m4.  And try to unpack on a local drive vice NFS.

Comment: I can't unpack it on my local drive since I don't have a compiler on my computer right now, so I'll try updating timestamps before I install a compiler, if you think that might work. I updated the configure.ac timestamp, and the multiple Makefile.am timestamps, but there was no acinclude.m4 file anywhere. It seemed to get a little farther this time, but now I am getting this: http://pastebin.com/0C9HSX2e. How can I fix that? Thanks for your help.